# AWS Cloudwatch encode query

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

When I run following query at AWS Console it doesn't match items:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream, @log 
    | filter @message like /Function.authenticatePerson (\/app\/controller\/people\/index.js:130:22)/
    | limit 200
    | sort @timestamp asc
```

But I am pretty sure logs is there since if I just use keyword "Function.authenticatePerson" it matches with some results.

Am I doing something wrong?